# Use of Global queryset in Django REST ViewSet Views/Actions

Tags: django, rest, view, action, django-queryset

Concerning the following Django REST code:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
"""
A viewset that provides the standard actions
"""
   queryset = User.objects.all()
   serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

When I try to use queryset in actions of this viewset, the following `error` is thrown:

> name 'queryset' is not defined

The Django REST documentation states that queryset should be declared outside views/actions so it can be used by all of them. Is this not the case? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Give more details. Full error trace  and Serializer

Comment: That's all that is shown for the error.

Comment: Mushahid, any insight into why this is happening?

Comment: Anyone experienced something similar? Your help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Actually the code is correct and it must work fine

Comment: Error may be in other part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use global querysets. Remember, any actions (GET, POST etc) inside your viewset class are accessing the variable inside the viewset object - queryset. So self.queryset is how you access it. See example code below:

```
def get(self, request):
    UserSerialized = self.UserSerializer(self.queryset, many=True)
    return Response(UserSerialized)
```

Hope that helps :)